# UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath odd behavior on first cell

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I've got a strange problem. In my app i've got a Table View with paging enabled and cells with full-screen height, only one cell is visible. Each cell has a button, and when the user taps it, scrollToRowAtIndexPath fires up, and table view scrolls to next cell. 
Unfortunately, while scrolling from first to second cell, first cell behaves oddly - it firstly disappears ( content view drops all subviews ), then it appears from the bottom of the screen, flows all the way up, and after it second cell appears. This issue doesn't reproduce on other cells - only while transition from first to second cell. The code i'm using is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
            let cells = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()?.sorted{ first, second in ((first as NSIndexPath).row) < ((second as NSIndexPath).row) }
    if let cells = cells {
        if cells.count > 0 {
            if let currentIndexPath = cells[0] as? NSIndexPath {
                let nextIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: currentIndexPath.row + 1, inSection: currentIndexPath.section)

               // UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                println("table view scrolls")

                if ( currentIndexPath.row + 1 >= self.tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0 ) )
                {
                    return ;
                }

                   self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(nextIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top , animated: true )


            }
        }
    }
}
```